# Not able to redirect a Django form after submission

Tags: python, django, forms

I am a newbie to Django and a form I created is giving me a bit of trouble.

I have create a form in Django for user authentication and login. But the form is not redirecting to the link I've specified after hitting submit. I think this is because the *authentication* function in `views.py` is returning the user as None. But this should not happen because the user exists in the database. I've confirmed this by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, which is Django's internal developer server.

The URL that I'm trying to redirect it to exists. No problems there.
The python files related to this are:

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

views.py:

I've omitted all the imports in the following code. No problems there.

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request):  # This function is executed if the server obtains a GET request.
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    '''
    The server gets a GET request every time a new user wants to register, i.e they want an empty form.
    That's why we pass None in the function above.
    It gets a POST request every time a filled form is submitted.
    '''

    def post(self, request): # This function is executed if the sever recevies a POST request.
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False) # This creates an object, but does not save it to the database.
            # Therefore, we can do some changes.

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            # Here, cleaned_data is converted data to suitable format. Like the date entered is converted to a
            # suitable format as its format is different all around the world.
            # Now you can change the username by user.username = 'some_name' or you can change the password by
            # user.set_password(new_password)

            user.save() # This line of code actually saves the code.

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # This checks if the user actually exists in the database.

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active: # This if the user is not banned or anything like that.
                    login(request, user) # This logs in the user.
                    return redirect('music:index')  # Redirects the user to index page.
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

        else:
            form = self.form_class(None)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    # This returns the filled form again if the the form is not valid.
```

The registration form template is (html file) :

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title%}Registration Form {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/index_style.css' %}" />

<div class="block">
    <form action="" method="post" >
         {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset> <!-- Gives it a better look by putting a heading and background around the form -->
            <legend>Create a new account:</legend><!-- This the common heading for the form -->
            {% include 'music/form_template.html' %}
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}>
```

The `form_template.html` included in the registration form template is:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Also, one other thing that is not normal is that whenever I create a new user by using the above form, the password for that user is being shown as:

> "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."

This can be seen at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ where we can edit the current users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

You correctly call `save` with commit=False, to allow you to set the hashed password before saving properly (as the comments state), but you never actually do so, so the user is saved with an unhashed password. This will never validate.

Similarly, you never set the user's is_active property, so the check a bit further down will always fail.

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
user.set_password(password)
user.is_active = True
user.save()
```